# I am trying to rewrite an RFID with a MEGA2560 and a RFID-RC522

Tags: rfid, code-review, atmega2560

I have been trying to rewrite an RFID tag so it is the same as my other one. I have code that will read both separately but I cannot find any already written for the MEGA2560 that will work for me. The code that works to read the RFID's is:

```
void setup()
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  /* Enable the SPI interface */
  SPI.begin(); 
  /* Initialise the RFID reader */
  RC522.init();
}

void loop()
{
  /* Has a card been detected? */
  if (RC522.isCard())
  {
    /* If so then get its serial number */
    RC522.readCardSerial();
    Serial.println("Card detected:");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    Serial.print(RC522.serNum[i],DEC);
    //Serial.print(RC522.serNum[i],HEX); //to print card detail in Hexa Decimal format
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

So I have been trying to mess around with code that was designed to clone the RFID that wasnt working for me before but I keep getting errors, mainly with double void looping etc. I have tried to fix the obvious issues. I am now getting an expected unqualified-id before 'if' but at this point I think I may just be making something that doesnt work. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could have a look at this and tell me where I am going wrong!

```
    /*
 * Copy the RFID card data into variables and then 
 * scan the second empty card to copy all the data
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Example sketch/program which will try the most used default keys listed in 
 * https://code.google.com/p/mfcuk/wiki/MifareClassicDefaultKeys to dump the
 * block 0 of a MIFARE RFID card using a RFID-RC522 reader.
 * 
 * Typical pin layout used:
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
 *
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

byte buffer[18];
byte block;
byte waarde[64][16];
MFRC522::StatusCode status;

MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;

// Number of known default keys (hard-coded)
// NOTE: Synchronize the NR_KNOWN_KEYS define with the defaultKeys[] array
#define NR_KNOWN_KEYS   8
// Known keys, see: https://code.google.com/p/mfcuk/wiki/MifareClassicDefaultKeys
byte knownKeys[NR_KNOWN_KEYS][MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE] =  {
    {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff}, // FF FF FF FF FF FF = factory default
    {0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5}, // A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
    {0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5}, // B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
    {0x4d, 0x3a, 0x99, 0xc3, 0x51, 0xdd}, // 4D 3A 99 C3 51 DD
    {0x1a, 0x98, 0x2c, 0x7e, 0x45, 0x9a}, // 1A 98 2C 7E 45 9A
    {0xd3, 0xf7, 0xd3, 0xf7, 0xd3, 0xf7}, // D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7
    {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff}, // AA BB CC DD EE FF
    {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}  // 00 00 00 00 00 00
};

char choice;
#include <SPI.h>
/* Include the RFID library */
#include <RFID.h>

/* Define the DIO used for the SDA (SS) and RST (reset) pins. */
#define SDA_DIO 9
#define RESET_DIO 8
/* Create an instance of the RFID library */
RFID RC522(SDA_DIO, RESET_DIO); 

void setup()
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  /* Enable the SPI interface */
  SPI.begin(); 
  /* Initialise the RFID reader */
  RC522.init();
}


  /* Has a card been detected? */
if (RC522.isCard())
  {
    /* If so then get its serial number */
    RC522.readCardSerial();
    Serial.println("Card detected:");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    Serial.print(RC522.serNum[i],DEC);
    //Serial.print(RC522.serNum[i],HEX); //to print card detail in Hexa Decimal format
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
  }
  delay(1000);
}

 //Via seriele monitor de bytes uitlezen in hexadecimaal

void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
        Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
}
//Via seriele monitor de bytes uitlezen in ASCI

void dump_byte_array1(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.write(buffer[i]);
  }
}

/*
 * Try using the PICC (the tag/card) with the given key to access block 0 to 63.
 * On success, it will show the key details, and dump the block data on Serial.
 *
 * @return true when the given key worked, false otherwise.
 */

bool try_key(MFRC522::MIFARE_Key *key)
{
    bool result = false;

    for(byte block = 0; block < 64; block++){

    // Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
    status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, key, &(mfrc522.uid));
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return false;
    }

    // Read block
    byte byteCount = sizeof(buffer);
    status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer, &byteCount);
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Read() failed: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    }
    else {
        // Successful read
        result = true;
        Serial.print(F("Success with key:"));
        dump_byte_array((*key).keyByte, MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE);
        Serial.println();

        // Dump block data
        Serial.print(F("Block ")); Serial.print(block); Serial.print(F(":"));
        dump_byte_array1(buffer, 16); //omzetten van hex naar ASCI
        Serial.println();

        for (int p = 0; p < 16; p++) //De 16 bits uit de block uitlezen
        {
          waarde [block][p] = buffer[p];
          Serial.print(waarde[block][p]);
          Serial.print(" ");
        }

        }
    }
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("1.Read card \n2.Write to card \n3.Copy the data.");

    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();       // Halt PICC
    mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD
    return result;

    start();
}

/*
 * Main loop.
 */
void loop() {
  start();

}

void start(){
  choice = Serial.read();

  if(choice == '1')
  {
    Serial.println("Read the card");
    keuze1();

    }
    else if(choice == '2')
    {
      Serial.println("See what is in the variables");
      keuze2();
    }
    else if(choice == '3')
    {
      Serial.println("Copying the data on to the new card");
      keuze3();
    }
}

void keuze2(){ //Test waardes in blokken

  for(block = 4; block <= 62; block++){
    if(block == 7 || block == 11 || block == 15 || block == 19 || block == 23 || block == 27 || block == 31 || block == 35 || block == 39 || block == 43 || block == 47 || block == 51 || block == 55 || block == 59){
      block ++;
    }

  Serial.print(F("Writing data into block ")); 
  Serial.print(block);
  Serial.println("\n");

    for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++){
      Serial.print(waarde[block][j]);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println("\n");

  }

  Serial.println("1.Read card \n2.Write to card \n3.Copy the data.");
  start();
}

void keuze3(){ //Copy the data in the new card
Serial.println("Insert new card...");
  // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
        return;

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
        return;

    // Show some details of the PICC (that is: the tag/card)
    Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
    dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
    MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
    Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

    // Try the known default keys
    /*MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
    for (byte k = 0; k < NR_KNOWN_KEYS; k++) {
        // Copy the known key into the MIFARE_Key structure
        for (byte i = 0; i < MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE; i++) {
            key.keyByte[i] = knownKeys[k][i];
        }
    }*/
    for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
    }

  for(int i = 4; i <= 62; i++){ //De blocken 4 tot 62 kopieren, behalve al deze onderstaande blocken (omdat deze de authenticatie blokken zijn)
    if(i == 7 || i == 11 || i == 15 || i == 19 || i == 23 || i == 27 || i == 31 || i == 35 || i == 39 || i == 43 || i == 47 || i == 51 || i == 55 || i == 59){
      i++;
    }
    block = i;

      // Authenticate using key A
    Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
    status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return;
    }

    // Authenticate using key B
    Serial.println(F("Authenticating again using key B..."));
    status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_B, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return;
    }

    // Write data to the block
    Serial.print(F("Writing data into block ")); 
    Serial.print(block);
    Serial.println("\n");

    dump_byte_array(waarde[block], 16); 


     status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, waarde[block], 16);
      if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
      }


     Serial.println("\n");

  }
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();       // Halt PICC
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD

  Serial.println("1.Read card \n2.Write to card \n3.Copy the data.");
  start();
}

void keuze1(){ //Read card
  Serial.println("Insert card...");
  // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
        return;

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
        return;

    // Show some details of the PICC (that is: the tag/card)
    Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
    dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
    MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
    Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

    // Try the known default keys
    MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
    for (byte k = 0; k < NR_KNOWN_KEYS; k++) {
        // Copy the known key into the MIFARE_Key structure
        for (byte i = 0; i < MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE; i++) {
            key.keyByte[i] = knownKeys[k][i];
        }
        // Try the key
        if (try_key(&key)) {
            // Found and reported on the key and block,
            // no need to try other keys for this PICC
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the second code? It has code outside of any function, so it cannot compile